# NullpointerException no mock da Repository

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, junit, mockito

Estou usando JUnit5 e ao criar o teste levo o seguinte erro:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.example.gerenciadordetarefas.repository.task.TaskRepository.save(Object)" because "this.taskRepository" is null

Alguém pode me ajudar a solucionar o erro acima?. Entendo que ele não consegue fazer mock da repository mas não sei o por que.  Aqui em baixo estão os códigos.

Obs: Minha service esta com a injeção de dependecia de User usando @Lazy por que eu estava tendo erro de circular dependencies.

Minha classe de teste :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class TaskServiceTest {
@Mock
private TaskRepository repository;
@InjectMocks
private  TaskService service ;

@Mock
private UserService userService;
private static final String TASK_ID_1 = "652d960af866034b686cca97";
private static final String TASK_ID_2 = "252d960af866034b686cca92";
private static final String USER_ID_1 = "642f6ab6813d692cef4795cc";

private final User user1 = User.builder()
        .id(USER_ID_1)
        .name("Maria Silva")
        .assignedTasks(new ArrayList<>())
        .build();
private final Task task = Task.builder()
        .title("teste")
        .description("teste aqui")
        .dateOfCreation(LocalDate.now())
        .dueDate(LocalDate.now())
        .assigne(Collections.singletonList(user1))
        .build();

private final TaskDto taskD = TaskDto.builder()
        .title("teste")
        .description("teste aqui")
        .dateOfCreation(LocalDate.now())
        .dueDate(LocalDate.now())
        .assigne(Collections.singletonList(USER_ID_1))
        .build();



@BeforeEach
void setUp() {


    Mockito.lenient().when(userService.getUserById(USER_ID_1)).thenReturn(user1);
    Mockito.lenient().when(repository.save(Mockito.any(Task.class))).thenReturn(task);
    Mockito.lenient().when(repository.findById(TASK_ID_1)).thenReturn(Optional.of(task));
}

@Test
@DisplayName("Verificar se o objeto Task está sendo criado ")
void createTask() {
    service.createTask(taskD);
    verify(repository, times(1)).save(task);

}
```

Minha Service:

```
@Service
public class TaskService {
@Autowired
private TaskRepository taskRepository;
private final UserService userService;
@Autowired
public TaskService(@Lazy UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}



public TaskDtoResponse createTask(TaskDto taskDto) {
    Task task = TaskMapper.taskDtoToTask(taskDto);
    this.addToAssigne(taskDto, task);
    taskRepository.save(task);
    return TaskMapper.taskToTaskDtoResponse(task);
}

public TaskDtoResponse updateTask(TaskDto dto, String id) {
    this.getTaskById(id);
    Task task = TaskMapper.taskDtoToTask(dto);
    this.addToAssigne(dto, task);
    task.setId(id);
    taskRepository.save(task);
    return TaskMapper.taskToTaskDtoResponse(task);
}

public Task addToAssigne(TaskDto taskDto, Task task){
    List<String>assigne = taskDto.getAssigne();
    assigne.forEach(id -> {
        User user = userService.getUserById(id);
        task.getAssigne().add(user);
    });
    return task;
}
```

Minha Repository:

```
@Repository
public interface TaskRepository extends MongoRepository<Task, String> {
@Query("{_id: {$in:?0}})")
List<Task> findByIds(List<String> ids);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está recebendo este erro porque o @InjectMocks não suporta injeção de dependência mista.

A classe TaskService tem dependência mista: UserService usa injeção no construtor, enquanto TaskRepository usa injeção na propriedade/atributo.

```java
@Service
public class TaskService {
  @Autowired
  private TaskRepository taskRepository;
  private final UserService userService;
  @Autowired
  public TaskService(@Lazy UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
  }
```

[A documentação do @InjectMock](https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html) diz que "Mockito injetará mocks apenas por um meio e nesta ordem: construtor, propriedades ou métodos."

Eu sugiro mover a injeção do TaskRepository para o construtor:

```java
@Service
public class TaskService {
  private final TaskRepository taskRepository;
  private final UserService userService;
  @Autowired
  public TaskService(@Lazy UserService userService, TaskRepository taskRepository) {
    this.userService = userService;
    this.taskRepository = taskRepository;
  }
```

Depois desta alteração, você vai ter que refatorar o código. Algo mais que eu gostaria de destacar é que o time do Spring recomenda usar dependência pelo construtor sempre que possível.

Comment: Muito obrigada, estava quebrando a cabeça aqui.